How to disallow newlines before or after comments with ESLint?
The @stylistic/lines-around-comment rule allows me to require new lines before or after comments, but I can't seem to find a way to disallow them. I thought the @stylistic/padding-line-between-statements rule might offer a way but it doesn't seem to touch comments at all.
